# how to convert JSONobject to JSonArray......?

Tags: android, arrays

I have Response

```
{

"p1":{
"date":"Sat, 29 Jul 2017 03:31:43 GMT",
"plan_id":"5c4c6548-38cb-4dbb-b7a3-a3f260fb8532",
"plan_name":"Ultra50",
"pulse":1,
"tarrif":1,
"validity":30
},
"p2":{
"date":"Sat, 29 Jul 2017 03:31:43 GMT",
"plan_id":"5c4c6548-38cb-4dbb-b7a3-a3f260fb8532",
"plan_name":"Ultra50",
"pulse":1,
"tarrif":1,
"validity":30
}
}
```

Here my Code

```
 Response.Listener<JSONObject> responseListener = new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {

                JSONObject plan=response.getJSONObject("p1");
                Iterator x=plan.keys();
                JSONArray jsonElements=new JSONArray();
                while (x.hasNext()){
                    String key=(String) x.next();
                    jsonElements.put(plan.get(key));
                    Log.e(TAG, "onResponse: "+key );

                }
                Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: "+jsonElements.toString());
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

how to convert p1,p2,p3 in one JsonArray?

Comment: Your question is not clear .

Comment: i want to this Json Response in listview... is it possible ? @IntelliJAmiya

Comment: Yes . why not..

Comment: how can tell me i want to show p1,p2,p3 object value in a list...@IntelliJAmiya

Comment: Check my answer .

Comment: Solved this yet ?

Comment: i m getting only last value in the adapter

Comment: show your current code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150819/discussion-between-shashank-priyadarshi-and-intellij-amiya).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use **[ITERATOR](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html)**.

> It is used to traverse a collection object elements one by one .

```
 Iterator  iteratorObj = response.keys();
        while (iteratorObj.hasNext())
        {
            String getKEY = (String)iteratorObj.next();
            System.out.println("Key: " + Key + "------>" + getKEY); // p1,p2
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

1. convert object to string
2. replace First { to [ and last } to ]
3. convert string to JSONArray

> ```
> String res = response.toString().trim();
>         res = res.replaceFirst("\{","]");
>         res = res.substring(0,res.length()-1) + "]";
>         try {
>                    JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(res.toString());
>         }catch (JSONException j)
>         {
>
>         }
> ```

Comment: i know but i cant change response.please give me a solution in an Android code...

Answer (score 1):

```
Iterator planKeys = response.keys();
{
    JSONArray jsonElements=new JSONArray();
    while(planKeys.hasNext()){
        String key = (String) planKeys.next();
        JSONObject plan = response.getJSONObject(key);
        Iterator x=plan.keys();
        while (x.hasNext()){
            String key=(String) x.next();
            jsonElements.put(plan.get(key));
            Log.e(TAG, "onResponse: "+key );

        }
    }
}

JSONObject plan=response.getJSONObject("p1");
```

Comment: Why `JSONArray ` ??

Comment: Because you have written in your question that you want JSONArray

Comment: create a model class and ArrayList<ModelClass> and add your jsonarray to list